# DropBox IOS SDk retrieving access token and secret is invalid once user is Authenticated

Tags: ios5, dropbox, dropbox-api

Cross authentication of a dropbox user using Access token and secret not happening.

Elaborating my Question:

1. authenticate the user in my IOS app
2. In Ios app , I retrieve access token and secret from MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore *credentials.
3. get the access token from credentials->acccessToken and similarly the secret.
4. Now if I feed these values into another app  outside IOS which uses python sdk for dropbox. I get a error message "Invalid token".

But, interestingly the reverse process from step 1 to 4 works. i.e get access token and secret from python SDK and feed it to my IOS app by using

```
[dbSession updateAccessToken:@"xxxxxxxxx" accessTokenSecret:@"YYYYYYYYYYY" forUserId:@"12345678"];
```

and now i can assess user's dropbox account. Any idea as to whats going wrong? Is there a difference between MPoauth and Oauth? I believe MPoauth is just a wrapper right?

is there any other way to get the access token and secret?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how come did you get the access token `crediantials.accessToken` returns null for me

Comment: I am guessing you are accessing it in the wrong place. do it in loadedAccountInfo() function.

Comment: @Alibaba I having a same issue. Can you please give me detail where I will get new auth2 access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for this. It was a simple error. Basically the editor I was using was adding a new line char at the end. For some one stuck at the same problem make sure you dont have a new line char at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your `Access token` by using this delegate

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *) url {

    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) { 
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) { 
            // At this point you can start making API calls

            NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");

        }
        // Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here 
     } 

     return NO;
 }
```

Given url has Access token, secret token and user id